# Why doesn't my form save the correct value?

Tags: cakephp

Ok, in CakePHP, I have the following code in my view `add.ctp`:

```
echo $this->Form->radio('color', array('1' => 'red', '2' => 'green', '3' => 'blue'), array('value' => false));
```

which results in the correct html:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Color</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="data[Some][color]" id="SomeColor1" value="1"  />
    <label for="SomeColor1">red</label>
    <input type="radio" name="data[Some][color]" id="SomeColor2" value="2"  />
    <label for="SomeColor2">green</label>
    <input type="radio" name="data[Some][color]" id="SomeColor3" value="3"  />
    <label for="SomeColor3">blue</label>
</fieldset>
```

If I check "green" for example, a `debug($this->data);` produces the expected result:

```
Array
(
    [Some] => Array
        (
            [color] => 2
        )

)
```

**However**, CakePHP inserts the wrong data in the table:

```
INSERT INTO `somes` (`color`) VALUES (1)
```

Any clue what's going on here? What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

- I am using `$this->Some->save($this->data)` and the datatype of color is `TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`.
- For the sake of the example I removed the other data, but basically, everything else works just fine and the record is saved.

Comment: What is the datatype of your `color` field?

Comment: We need to see your controller code. Are you using `$this->Color->save()` ?

Comment: see above. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cakePHP considers tinyInt(1) to be a Boolean so.. 0=0  and >0 =1

Answer (score 2):

This is because of TINYINT(1). Change it for example TINYINT(3) and your data will be saved correctly.